# Destroying session in php is SLOW working

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, timeout

I wrote this code at the begin of the **survey.php** file:

```
<?php 
    //Check if session set 
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        session_start();

    //Check if un user login or no
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        //check if the user is admin
        if($_SESSION['type']==1)
            header( 'Location: admin.php');
    }
    // check if no user login
    else
        //Go to first page
        header( 'Location: index.php');

    //Check if thimeout is finished.
    if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < time()-$_SESSION['expire_time'] ) { 
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        //Go to first page
        header('Location: index.php'); 
    } 
    else{ 
        $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
    }
?>
```

I put the comments inside.

After finishing timeout for going to **index.php** page the site become very slow then it goes to **index.php**

But if I clean the cookies by **google chrome** it become fast like before.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself,

I don't like the method that I used but it works.

If anyone have any recommendation, I'll be happy.

That was because of `header('Location: index.php');`

I write

```
if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < time()-$_SESSION['expire_time'] ) { 
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    //header('Location: index.php'); 
    echo "Session expired click <a href=\"index.php\">here</a> for going in login page.";
    exit(0);

    //Go to first page
}
```